# I want to automate F2+Enter without using sendkeys. Nothing is working for the text which I have extracted from a word table

Tags: excel, vba

I am extracting text from a word table using excel VBA. When I write this data in excel sheet all the chr(10) are not visible and the text is followed by a box which looks like[]. On double clicking the cell expands and chr(10)/'alt+enter' become visible. I need to automate this process without using sendkey.

The way i am writing the required text from word table to excel sheet cells is shown below:

```
//opened the word file, located the table, then

For iRows = 2 To iTotalRows
     For iCols = 1 To iTotalCols
        txt = Trim(objDoc.Tables(iTable).Cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Text)                    
        Sheet1.Cells(iRows, iCols) = Replace(txt, " ", "") 
     Next iCols
Next iRows
```

Before:

[image: This is how the cells look like before F2+Enter]
[image: This is how the cells look like after F2+Enter]

Comment: Record a macro of you pressing `F2` and `Enter`, and go from there.

Comment: What does pressing f2 and enter do?

Comment: wrap your replace in another one to get rid of the chr(10)'s: `Replace(Replace(txt, " ", ""),Chr(10),"")`

Comment: chr(10) are required as they are the delimiter for further functioning. I just what them to be shown at the first place. When I press F2+Enter they showup, otherwise they don't. Please refer linked images in the question.

Comment: Also I have written a macro using sendkeys which works fine but takes a lot of time traversing through each cell. Also if I set Application.ScreenUpdating = false, the macro doesn't work.

Comment: Try to activate wrap text `Sheet1.Cells(iRows, iCols).WrapText = True` for the cells.